# Report, Ad hoc report and Dashboard in pentaho

Tags: report, scheduled-tasks, pentaho, dashboard, saiku

I'm currently working on a project to implement a BI solution. I chose Pentaho

There are many tools to create:

reports (**report designer**)

adhoc reports (**WAHQR** ou PIR)

Dashboard (dashboard designer or **CDE**)

Analyze (analyzer or **saiku**)

(in big the one I'll use)

The question is, which tool is used by the final user (non technic) and which by the technician/developer?

And which of these tools create report/dashboard that can be executed repeatedly with a scheduler / just one time on demand?

thks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer : All

User      : SAIKU

Reports generated by Pentaho Report Dssigner could be excuted by scheduler. This is also able to be executed by scheduler using kitchen using Pentaho Reporting Output step.

Comment: With your first solution: I have to schedule it on the server right?

With the second one it looks like a bit more tricky. I have to create a report with PRD (just empty report with no data?) and then use it in my PDI and fullfill it with the data I get in PDI?

Comment: CDE can be excuted regularly or is it executed everytime the user ask for it?